# Closing a question should remove/hide protection notice

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, protected-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Don't display “protected” notice if the question is locked or closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131638/dont-display-protected-notice-if-the-question-is-locked-or-closed)

Currently, if a question that is protected is closed, it continues to show the protection notice along with the close notice.

Because a closed question can't receive new answers, the protection notice should not be displayed.  After all, protection is part of an attempt to keep crappy new answers from creeping up on what are considered very good, even canonical questions (and answers), but no one can add answers on closed questions, so the two notices are a little bit at odds with each other.

To that end, can we hide or remove the protection notice when a question is closed?  Note the protection isn't actually removed, it just isn't *shown*..

Because it's only hidden, if the question is reopened, then protection would still be on the question and the notice would appear.

This is really just about removing an obvious conflict between post notices when a question is closed (more fit-and-finish type work).

Comment: What benefit is there from removing the protection (other than removing the notice?)

Comment: @ChrisF Protection implies that the question is a good fit from the site, since we want to restrict the kind of answers on it.  Also, it's an oxymoron.  Protection limits answers.  Answers cannot be provided on closed questions.  I'd like to see that conflict between those statements removed while the question is closed.  Since the close reason is the one that matters, the protection notice doesn't apply.  It's about fit-and-finish.

Comment: Why not just hide the protection notice on closed questions?

Comment: @Toomai Updated the title and post to reflect that, that's more elegant than removing the actual protection.  There's just no need to actually see it.