# Why an unprotect option shown for a question which was not protected?

Tags: support, specific-question, protected-questions

While viewing [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4113/which-time-tracker-application-do-you-recommend) question, i'm just wondered of why all the options(*share, edit, reopen,delete,flag,unprotect*) are shown in two lines instead of a one single line. Is this a bug?

And also i have another question. This same question also wasn't protected then why an **unprotect** option instead of **protect**?

[image]

Comment: then  why it's not shown?

Comment: See this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131638/dont-display-protected-notice-if-the-question-is-locked-or-closed

Answer (score 7):

The post **is** protected, but there is [little point in showing the notification on a question that has been closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131638/dont-display-protected-notice-if-the-question-is-locked-or-closed); **no one** can post, not just new users.

See the [post revision history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/4113/revisions):

> Question Protected by Community♦   - occurred Feb 9 '13 at 19:46